# Current time in setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setInterval(function() {
      var current = ? getCurrentInterval ? ;
      alert(current);
}, 2000);
```

Is possible to check?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: What do you want? Count the triggered intervals or get the current time? Be specific.

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking, the current machine time? A counter? If a counter, keep a counter.

Comment: I think he wants how many milliseconds into the current interval it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing that will give you the "current" interval, as there might be several distinct timers running. You might be better off constructing your own `Timer` class that stores the interval and that you can later query.

You're going to have to be a little creative with Javascript's scoping contexts if you have multiple timers and need to access the relevant `Timer` inside your callback. Something along these lines:

```
function Timer(timeout) {
    var self = this;
    this.interval = timeout ? timeout : 1000;   // Default

    this.run = function (runnable) {
        setInterval(function () { runnable(self); }, this.interval);
    };
}

var timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.run(function (timer) {
    alert(timer.interval);
});
```