# How to persist setInterval function even when page is refreshed in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute a function at certain interval and I can use *setInterval* for that but the problem is, each time I refresh a page, setInterval's counter is started again!

So, how can I execute a function at certain Interval even when the page is refreshed?

```
 setInterval(function(){
   console.log("test"); //function is called here              
   }, 10000);
```

This has to be executed at every 10 secs even when the page is refreshed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a implementation using `localStorage` to save the time:

```
function setupInterval (callback, interval, name) {
  var key = '_timeInMs_' + (name || '');
  var now = Date.now();
  var timeInMs = localStorage.getItem(key);
  var executeCallback = function () {
    localStorage.setItem(key, Date.now());
    callback();
  }
  if (timeInMs) { // User has visited
    var time = parseInt(timeInMs);
    var delta = now - time;
    if (delta > interval) { // User has been away longer than interval
      setInterval(executeCallback, interval);
    } else { // Execute callback when we reach the next interval
      setTimeout(function () {
        setInterval(executeCallback, interval);
        executeCallback();
      }, interval - delta);
    }
  } else {
    setInterval(executeCallback, interval);
  }
  localStorage.setItem(key, now);
}

setupInterval(function () {
  console.log("test"); // function is called here
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the data even after page refresh, you have to use `localStorage` for that purpose.

You can set and get your counter value using the following code

`localStorage.setItem(key,value);` to set
`localStorage.getItem(key);` to get.

Note that the value store in the localstorage is string format, so you need to convert it to integer when you are using get function to get your counter value.

For more info on localstorage you can refer the below post.
[Setting and getting localStorage with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791207/setting-and-getting-localstorage-with-jquery)

Comment: Ok, but how can I set the current status of the setInterval timer and get it after page refresh?

Comment: you mean to say that, when the setInetrval Function is call the 10 sec timer reset and suppose after 6 sec the page is refreshed, then the setInterval function should be called in 4 sec for 1st time in the refereshed page and then again in 10 sec?

Comment: Yes. Exactly! That is what it should be like!

Comment: You cannot get the time of the SetInterval. You have to create your own timer as mentioned in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578006/current-time-in-setinterval.