# Is there a way to get the interval using the this method?

Tags: javascript, methods, get, setinterval

So, imagine the following code below:

```
setInterval(() => {
    var thisInterval = this;
    fn1();
    fn2();
    if(someMouseDownEventDeclaredSomewhereElse){
        clearInterval(thisInterval);
    }
},100);
```

Is `this` the correct method for getting the current interval? Say I wanna do so without setting a variable to this loop because I want it to be an unnamed and non-stored interval. In simpler words: Is there a way to get an unnamed interval from within, like with `this` or something?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Current time in setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578006/current-time-in-setinterval)

Comment: No, there are some tricks and hacks but there is no option to get intervalId without storing it somewhere. Could you please let us know why you can't store interval ID? Maybe that is the problem that is possible to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this;

```
function f() {
    fn1();
    fn2();
    if(!someMouseDownEventDeclaredSomewhereElse){
        setTimeout(f, 100);
    }
}
setTimeout(f, 100);
```

Comment: Seems easy enough :)

Comment: Though, I am looking for how to GET the interval, but the program I am making could benefit from this. Thank you!